# Read array of byte until new line - golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I want to read a file from S3. This file contains several lines, and In each line, there is a string.

something like:

```
Alice
Bob
Jack
```

I have an API that reads my file, but the output is: []byte

How can I split the byte array by a new line and convert them to string? My Desire output is an array of strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a slice of strings from a slice of bytes, [convert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) the slice of bytes to a string and [split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) the string on newline:

```
 lines := strings.Split(string(fileContents), "\n")
```

Comment: Requires reading the entire file into memory, but files are usually small enough that  doesn't matter.  If you should ever need to read the file progressively, something like https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader.ReadLine doesn't require reading it all at once

Comment: @DanielFarrell OP requested slice strings from a slice of bytes and that's what this answer delivers.  Your comment is better directed at the question.